# Error in the minimum value of the operational amplifier output

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, analog, filter

I designed a circuit to control the speed of a 24V coller. For this I used the operational amplifier `TCA0372DW`.

As I am going to control the output voltage through a PWM signal that comes from the STM32, it was necessary to create an RC filter to convert the PWM signal into analog.

**0% duty cycle = 0V**

**50% duty cycle = 1.65V**

**100% duty cycle = 3.3V**

I determined the gain of the amplifier as follows: **Vo / Vi = (R30 / R27) +1**

With that I have a gain of approximately 7.3.
Theoretically for:

**Vi = 0V ------ Vo = 0V**

**Vi = 1.65V ------ Vo = 12.045**

**Vo = 3.3V ------ Vo = 24.09**

But this is not happening for input voltages near 0V. With the minimum input value I have at the 4V output and this affects the functioning of my system.

I know that there is a saturation in the amplifier that makes it never reach the maximum value of 24V. But I couldn't understand why for values close to 0V the output remains at 4V.

[image]
[image: Input: 3.3V Output: 22.4V]
[image: Input: V Output: 4V]

Comment: Return R27 to 1.2V (made by a resistor to +V and 2 diodes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Page 3 of the [spec sheet](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/TCA0372-D.PDF) indicates that the output swing of that part is 1.3V to 22.7V nominal.  If you want it to go all the way to the rail, you need a rail-to-rail part or a negative supply.

Your first stage is probably pegged at somewhere around 0.6V (it's allowed to perform better than the spec).  The factor of 7 gain in the second stage brings it up to around 4V.

Answer (score 1):

[image: out]

In this configuration, the minimum output voltage (no load) is approx. 0.5V. This is the first amplifier. The second amplifies this signal 7.3x, so its output will have a minimum of 3.65V. At least the first one should be replaced with a right one. Eg LM358, then the output voltage will be 5mV without load at first amplifier.